# Android: Not valid resource file

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have just downloaded latest `Android Studio 3.0 Preview Canary 2`. It has updated my project with latest gradle `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2`. And now I have a lot of compile crashes like:

```
ERROR: C:\Users\??????\\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-25.3.1.aar\a33e01f0d19405567201ecab1e032796\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notification_bg_low_normal.9.png not a valid resource file

ERROR: C:\Users\??????\\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-25.3.1.aar\a33e01f0d19405567201ecab1e032796\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notification_bg_low_normal.9.png not a valid resource file

ERROR: C:\Users\??????\\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-25.3.1.aar\ab2edc05ef7bbad4b3861a867a381098\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\design_ic_visibility.png not a valid resource file

ERROR: C:\Users\??????\\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-25.3.1.aar\ab2edc05ef7bbad4b3861a867a381098\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\design_ic_visibility.png not a valid resource file

ERROR: C:\Users\??????\\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-25.3.1.aar\a33e01f0d19405567201ecab1e032796\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png not a valid resource file

ERROR: C:\Users\??????\\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-25.3.1.aar\a33e01f0d19405567201ecab1e032796\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png not a valid resource file

ERROR: C:\Users\??????\\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-25.3.1.aar\a33e01f0d19405567201ecab1e032796\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png not a valid resource file

ERROR: C:\Users\??????\\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-25.3.1.aar\a33e01f0d19405567201ecab1e032796\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png not a valid resource file


ERROR: C:\Users\??????\\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-25.3.1.aar\a33e01f0d19405567201ecab1e032796\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000.png not a valid resource file

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 compile failed: aapt2 compile -o D:\AndroidProjects\GetPet\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug C:\Users\user\\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-25.3.1.aar\ab2edc05ef7bbad4b3861a867a381098\res\layout\design_navigation_item.xml Issues:
   - ERROR: C:\Users\user\\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-25.3.1.aar\ab2edc05ef7bbad4b3861a867a381098\res\layout\design_navigation_item.xml not a valid resource file
```

I have tried to clean project and gradle cache, but useless.

My `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And `app\build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'alias'
            keyPassword 'pass'
            storeFile file('release_keystor.jks')
            storePassword 'pass'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.org.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.vk:androidsdk:1.6.5'
}
```

Comment: You're welcome to delete `C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches` if that's the problem

Comment: @cricket_007, as I wrote before, I tried it before. Result is the same

Comment: "The new Android plugin requires Gradle version 4.0-milestone-1 or higher." https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html

Comment: @cricket_007, Android Studio applied it automatically

Comment: My only other thoughts would be that you're using the preview build, which is primarily targeted to be used for Android O or Java 8 development, I believe, but you're using `25.3.1` and SDK 25, so why did you upgrade?

Comment: @cricket_007, I would like to try `Kotlin` first of all. And maybe then some new Android features.

Comment: Did you try to use a version of the support libraries less than `25.3.1`? I know that's the latest, but it seems your resources are corrupt

Comment: @cricket_007, using `25.0.0` or `24.0.0` has the same result as `25.3.1`. Even when I create new project I have same crashes. Maybe not today

Comment: Well, you definitely need 25 version since that's the compile sdk. If all else fails, I'd use the SDK Manager to re-download things since its all cached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change **service directory path** to something **without cyrillic symbols**, like "C:/gradle" in

> Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle

And don't forget to invalidate caches.

Comment: Where is the cyrillic symbols?

Comment: Instead of a question marks in path **C:\Users\??????\.gradle**. I've had the same problem and my Windows username is *Максим* in Russian. I think the author has Russian username too, because he uses a VK SDK.

Comment: The question marks are only to hide the name of the person. I don't think it's literal

Comment: Maybe, but I've had exactly the same error with the question marks in gradle build message and the path change is helped me.

Comment: Hmm, at the bottom of the question is does have 
`ERROR: C:\Users\user\\.gradle`

Comment: @МаксимКругликов you right. Android Studio in error message changed my cyrillic username to `??????` and I didn't think that it can be a clue  of a problem