# NoClassDefFoundError during project sync in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio stopped working. Project can't be synced. I receive an error:

project refresh failed
Error:C:\Users\?????.gradle\native\23\windows-i386\native-platform.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Logs for Google:

```
Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native
at com.intellij.util.text.DateFormatUtil.getWindowsFormats(DateFormatUtil.java:433)
at com.intellij.util.text.DateFormatUtil.getDateTimeFormats(DateFormatUtil.java:335)
at com.intellij.util.text.DateFormatUtil.<clinit>(DateFormatUtil.java:59)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.status.StatusPanel$5.run(StatusPanel.java:218)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.status.StatusPanel.updateText(StatusPanel.java:225)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.status.InfoAndProgressPanel.setText(InfoAndProgressPanel.java:479)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.status.IdeStatusBarImpl.lambda$setInfo$3(IdeStatusBarImpl.java:465)
at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2432)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.status.IdeStatusBarImpl.setInfo(IdeStatusBarImpl.java:463)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusConnectionImpl.java:117)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.doPumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:377)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:364)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:350)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.sendMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:343)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$200(MessageBusImpl.java:42)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$2.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:226)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.setInfo(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.StatusBar$Info.set(StatusBar.java:57)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.StatusBar$Info.set(StatusBar.java:43)
at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel.setStatusBarText(LinkLabel.java:273)
at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel.disableUnderline(LinkLabel.java:265)
at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel.removeNotify(LinkLabel.java:201)
at java.awt.Container.removeNotify(Container.java:2804)
at javax.swing.JComponent.removeNotify(JComponent.java:4758)
at java.awt.Container.removeNotify(Container.java:2804)
at javax.swing.JComponent.removeNotify(JComponent.java:4758)
at java.awt.Container.removeAll(Container.java:1297)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.status.InfoAndProgressPanel.buildInProcessCount(InfoAndProgressPanel.java:325)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.status.InfoAndProgressPanel.removeProgress(InfoAndProgressPanel.java:257)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.status.InfoAndProgressPanel.access$800(InfoAndProgressPanel.java:64)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.status.InfoAndProgressPanel$MyInlineProgressIndicator.lambda$finish$0(InfoAndProgressPanel.java:684)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$6.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:291)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:326)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:310)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:631)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

And more:

```
Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef$ULONGLONG.<clinit>(WinDef.java:843)
at com.intellij.ui.Win7TaskBar.<clinit>(Win7TaskBar.java:50)
at com.intellij.ui.AppIcon$Win7AppIcon._hideProgress(AppIcon.java:410)
at com.intellij.ui.AppIcon$BaseIcon.hideProgress(AppIcon.java:101)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl$AppIconProgress.lambda$finish$1(DumbServiceImpl.java:561)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:631)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

And more:

```
Could not initialize class com.intellij.ui.Win7TaskBar
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.intellij.ui.Win7TaskBar
at com.intellij.ui.AppIcon$Win7AppIcon._hideProgress(AppIcon.java:410)
at com.intellij.ui.AppIcon$BaseIcon.hideProgress(AppIcon.java:101)
at com.intellij.ui.AppIcon$BaseIcon$1.applicationActivated(AppIcon.java:150)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusConnectionImpl.java:117)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.doPumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:377)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:364)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.sendMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:343)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$200(MessageBusImpl.java:42)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$2.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:226)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.applicationActivated(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.ide.ApplicationActivationStateManager.setActive(ApplicationActivationStateManager.java:135)
at com.intellij.ide.ApplicationActivationStateManager.updateState(ApplicationActivationStateManager.java:83)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.processAppActivationEvents(IdeEventQueue.java:758)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:520)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
at java.awt.SequencedEvent.dispatch(SequencedEvent.java:128)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:631)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Yesterday everything worked fine. Nothing has been changed.
I reinstalled Android Studio. The problem is still here.

Help me please!!!

Comment: `C:\Users\?????\.gradle`... I assume you username isnt a bunch of question marks?

Comment: this might help you https://discuss.gradle.org/t/running-gradle-failed-to-load-native-platform-dll-error/18863/4

Comment: @cricket_007 My username consists of cyrillic letters. And it wasn't a problem earlier.

Comment: I think something has been updated. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44221820/2308683

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for helpful link. I created new user with ASCII letters only name, reinstalled Android Studio. It works fine again! If you want, you can publish it as answer. I'll chech it as correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think's it a bug in some latest version of something

> My username consists of cyrillic letters

Which explains `C:\Users\?????\.gradle\`

It can't load any files under the path `C:\Users\?????`, so it fails.

Solution until whatever bug is fixed: Make a user account without cyrillic letters